# Super permutations

Tags: code-golf, string, combinatorics, permutations

## Super permutations

Input: A string
The program should loop through all lengths of the input (decrementing one each time), generate all combinations with replacement of the string, then make permutations out of  the generated combinations, and display all of the strings.
They can be separated with anything (doesn't need to be a comma)

Example for the string 'abc':

```
a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc
aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, aca, acb, acc
baa, bab, bac, bba, bbb, bbc, bca, bcb, bcc
caa, cab, cac, cba, cbb, cbc, cca, ccb, ccc
```

The values don't necessarily have to be sorted.
Avoid any standard loop holes.

Comment: Can we also include the empty string as a length zero permutation?

Comment: Will the string contain duplicates? If so, do you need the output to be deduplicated?

Comment: I tagged this code golf, because all the answers are assuming it is.

Comment: I'm finding the talk of permutations and combinations confusing here. The way I'd phrase the task is: output all strings made of characters in the input, whose length ranges from 1 to the length of the input. Related: [Output all strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74273/20260).

Comment: Can we take a length argument?

Comment: Can we output a list of lists? Like `[[a,b], [aa,ab,ba,bb]]`? Some answers already assume this, while others flatten the list

Answer (score 16):

## Scratch 3.0, 65 blocks / <s>637</s> 632 bytes

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

[image: Part 3]

[image: Part 4]

Look at y'all, having fun with your fancy shmancy permutation functions/map tools. Well, not I! ***No***, not I! When using Scratch, one has to do things themselves! You won't find any built-ins around these parts! *I'm just glad there still ain't any `goto`s ;)*

But more seriously, the image is split into 4 parts because *it's just soooo long*
Press space to clear the lists before each run

And finally,

[Try it on<s>line</s> Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/362536859/)

As SB Syntax:

```
when gf clicked
set[c v]to(0
ask()and wait
set[L v]to(length of(answer
add(1)to[b v
repeat((L)-(1
add(0)to[b v
end
repeat until<(c)=(1
set[s v]to(0
set[l v]to(1
repeat(length of[b v
change[s v]by(item(l)of[b v
change[l v]by(1
end
if<(s)=((L)*(L))>then
set[c v]to(1
end
set[r v]to(
set[l v]to(1
repeat(length of[b v
set[r v]to(join(r)(letter(item(i)of[b v])of(answer
change[i v]by(1
end
add(r)to[o v
replace item(1)of[b v]with((item(1)of[b v])+(1
set[j v]to(1
repeat(length of[b v
if<(item(j)of[b v])>(length of(answer))>then
replace item(j)of[b v]with(1
replace item((j)+(1))of[b v]with((item((j)+(1))of[b v])+(1
end
change[j v]by(1
```

*-5 bytes due to not being a silly billy and removing extranous spaces*

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to a'_'*

```
ā€ã
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SOOjpjWHF///n5iU/B8A)

Comment: I don't know 05AB1E. I just randomly pasted a character inside the program. [And it WORKS!?](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SOOjpjWHF///n5iU/B8A)

Comment: @a'_' you what? That sounds insanely unlikely lol

Comment: @Cruncher I am serious. I thought turning the `gL` into `ã` (i.e. a double-cartesian power) would work. It turns out that I copied the wrong character (`ā` indeed looks very similar to `ã`)

Comment: (And then I feel that *pretending* that I don't know 05AB1E and saying *randomly* will make viewers laugh harder.)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṗJ
```

A monadic Link which accepts a list of characters and returns a list of lists of lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzule/w@3u///r56YlKwOAA)** (footer formats as a grid)

#### How?

```
ṗJ - list, S
 J - range of length of S
ṗ  - Cartesian power (vectorises)
```

If we must output a flat list of "strings" (lists of characters) [we can add `Ẏ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzuleD3f1/T/c7v3/v3piUrI6AA) (tighten) for the cost of a byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
f s=init$mapM(\_->s)=<<scanr(:)[]s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBDYAgDADAVRrCAx4sYMANnECNqY0oEQihzG@9e5DfK2eRCBxSTUMXbIvZDjezDd4zYe1msuvOUjBVCNB6qgM0RFB4kpKPYsabxVFrPw)

Here's how it works, using input `s="abc"`:

```hs
                       scanr(:)[]s
```

Produces the suffixes of `s`, `["abc","bc","c",""]`, by prepending each character in turn to the front and tracking the intermediate results.

```hs
         mapM(\_->s)
```

Uses the list monad to map each element to `s`, that is, `'xy'-> ["abc","abc"]`, and take multiply them as a Cartesian product, here giving `["aa","ab","ac","ba","bb","bc","ca","cb","cc"]`.

```hs
         mapM(\_->s)=<<scanr(:)[]s
```

Uses `=<<` as `concatMap` to take the function above that uses `mapM` and apply it to each of the suffixes, thereby producing the Cartesian products of copies of `s` numbering from 0 to its length, in a single list.

```hs
    init$
```

Removes the empty string, produces from the suffix of length `0`.

```hs
f s=
```

Declares the function.

Comment: What is going on here?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
gENIã)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3dXP8/Bizf//E5OS/wMA)

## Explanation

```
gENIã)
 E     # foreach in...
g      # the input
    ã  # find the cartesian product of...
   I   # the input...
  N    # repeat N
     ) # wrap the final stack to an array
       # implicit output of the top element
```

Comment: That looks like _genial_, which in my (natural) language means _brilliant_. +1 for that

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
a:-.~[:,#\{@#"{<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/E6109eqirXSUY6odlJWqbf5rcqUmZ@QrpCmoJyYlq/8HAA)

- `a:-.~` Remove empty boxes from...
- `[:,` The flatten of...
- `{@#"{` The Catalog (cross prod) of `{@`...
- `#\{@#"{<`

  - `<` The boxed input...
  - `#"{` Copied this many times...
  - `#\` 1, 2, ... N, where N is the input length.  That is, we copy the input once, then twice, ... then N times, taking the Catalog of each of those.

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>176</del> <del>174</del> <del>173</del> <del>171</del> <del>170</del> 166 bytes

```php
$c=$t=count($u=array_values(array_unique(str_split($argn))));for($s=1;$i<$t**$t;){$i-$c?:[$s++,$c*=$t,$i=0];for($k=$i++,$j=0;$j<$s;$j++,$k/=$t)echo$u[$k%$t];echo',';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxLCsIwAESv4mKk6Q/r1jR05yVKKSVUExuamI8g4tWNKZ3FwGMeY4SJbWeEOURwBs@4DqsnCGyydnqPr0mF2ZEdwiqfYSbO29EZJZM22fuap9CbtgSOnSlkC18U8DT/QNbg3aWHK8sKvEj/FSRrhl1fGOQ2PFhD8WjhUm@8nJKYz1xohB7LEX6gG2VVRr8xilkp/dPGS726WF//)

-4 bytes thanks to @Ismael Miguel.

Method: simply count in base N, where N is the number of unique characters in the input string.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by moving `$k/=$t;` into the `for($j=0;$j<$s;$j++)`, and remove the `{...}`, like this: `for($j=0;$j<$s;$j++,$k/=$t)echo$u[$k%$t];`

Comment: Didn't think PHP supported the comma operator. But yes, in for loops!

Comment: Oh, it works. And here's something else: you can replace your `if($i==$c){$s++;$c*=$t;$k=$i=0;}` with `$i==$c?[$s++,$c*=$t,$k=$i=0]:0;`. This will save 1 byte, and work the same. This uses a [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and an array, where the array will be "executed" if the condition is true. However, you need to have a value for the `false` condition (the `0`). What saves the byte is really the array, because you remove the `;` after the 3rd assignment, when changing the syntax.

Comment: Very clever, I shall use it in future. I switched the condition however, for one extra byte: $i!=$c?:[$s++,$c*=$t,$k=$i=0];

Comment: That is actually really clever. I didn't though about it. But hey, 5 bytes shaved from the total is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 42 bytes

```
($a=$args)|%{($p=$p|%{$t=$_;$a|%{$t+$_}})}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoQwEATv84pBWqPs/mAZ8CdhIuoeBEMUPMR5e9bspbr6UnG/5nR8520rWCSXHirQtB7D3eYeURAfwSnwH@hfX/BmgxUjchom92anFSGEOrW1O765zcSMxMIdY@HRP7dBasio/AA).

Expects input via [splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

Comment: via `$null`. it's smart!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 95 bytes

```
import itertools as i;lambda s:[''.join(p)for l in range(len(s))for p in i.product(s,repeat=l)]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##rcwxDsIwDADAnVdYXepIqAsbqC9BDG6bgFFqW44ZeH0QvIH1hrN3PFROvfNu6gEc2UO1NqAGfKm0LxtBO1/HcXoqC1oq6lCBBZzknrFmwZZ@al/lyVy31xrYjp4tU8w13XqBGf62HcxZAgsOtKzbkFL/AA)

Comment: Using `l` here made me confuse it with `1` for a second back in the `repeat=` part... +1!

Comment: @ojdo maybe not the best choice on my part :P

Comment: Note: you can format your TIO code like [this](https://tio.run/##HcgxDsIwDADAnVdYXepIqAsbUl8CDG6bgFFqW4478PoguPHsEy@VSy8ww71X2peNoF1v4zi9lQUtFXWowAJO8sxYs2BL/7Xf8mSu27EGtrNnyxRzTY8T76YewJE9VGsDasDdnCWw4EDLug0p9S8) for anonymous lambdas with imports

Comment: @JoKing That does look better! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque),  <s>5</s>  4 bytes

```
sacb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/ODE56f//xKRkAA)

-1 thanks to DeathIncarnate!

```
sa    # Duplicate the input and get it's length
  cb  # Get all combinations of the input characters up to the length of the input
```

Comment: sa is shorthand for JL[ [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/ODE56f//xKRkAA "Burlesque – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,A={''}:s in A and A or f(s,A|{a+c for a in A for c in s})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NCsIwEITP@hQLHtLQUETBQ6GHPod42PxhqE1KEoRS@@wxqdLL7jc77DDTHJ/OXlLS3QtHLhEC67uFkLUNYCz0gFbm6TzoKlufBWsBOkv82QVFwbDSVMT2difIBWFAEHFbXEjyaI@HyRsbIezgfFSyytGUwaDmvUSb3SrU5EzY9UYpnCA6GHFQYCJwUBiM8uXmFcqt41t5o@emaf7Z6Qs)

Outputs a set; includes the empty string.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 71 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,A=[]:s in A and A or f(s,set(s)|{a+c for a in A for c in s})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRoVjH0TY61qpYITNPwVEhMS8FSOYXKaRpFOsUp5ZoFGvWVCdqJyukAcUSIWpAzGQQs7hW839BUWZeCVC1emJSsrrmfwA)

If empty string is not allowed...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 90 bytes

Returns a Set.

```javascript
s=>new Set([...Array(n=(L=-~s.length)**~-L)].map(_=>(g=n=>n?[s[n%L-1]]+g(n/L|0):'')(n--)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcsxCwIhFADgvV/REr53odUaeNHu1igSZp4V9jxUiiDur9vtrR98D/uyxeX7WDmlq2@DbEX25N/Lk6@ghRDHnO0HSIKSfCoiegr1hl03cYVGPO0IZ9lDkDS3gy6aVorvjFkHoI36bnHPGAJxjojNJSopehFTgAGYvTDExR@6WdsP)

#### Commented

```javascript
s => new Set(            // build a set from
  [...Array(             //   an array of
    n =                  //   n entries, with:
      (L = -~s.length)   //     n = L ** (L - 1)
      ** ~-L             //     where L is the length of s + 1
  )]                     //   
  .map(_ =>              //   for each entry:
    ( g = n =>           //     g is a recursive function taking n
        n ?              //       if n is not equal to 0:
          [s[n % L - 1]] //         output s[(n mod L) - 1]
                         //         or an empty string if it's undefined
          + g(n / L | 0) //         recursive call with floor(n / L)
        :                //       else:
          ''             //         stop recursion
    )(n--)               //     initial call to g; decrement n afterwards
  )                      //   end of map()
)                        // end of Set()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
ＦＥθＸＬθ⊕κＥι✂⍘⁺ικθ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxDsIwDATQX/HoSmHozMZWCaRI/QJjTBs1JK2bwuebpDfe3eOZlDNFs3dWwAetuDnw@SeKd0lTmXHrHAyJVT6Sirxw6WrAa0jl/AcHYwwseKNdxlL7CX089jYs1TbfV3I1oyfb5Rv/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＥθＸＬθ⊕κ
```

Loop over the substring lengths and raise the length to each power in turn.

```
Ｅι✂⍘⁺ικθ¹
```

Loop from each power to double its value and perform base conversion using the input string as the alphabet, then slice off the first character.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

Total Husk novice, there may be better ways to golf this.

```
Mπŀ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/d8w9GGQzv///@vlJiUrAQA)

## Explanation

```
  ŀ¹ Find the range [1, ..., len(input)]
Mπ   Map with cartesian power of input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 60 bytes

```ruby
->s{a,*z=s.chars,'';z.product(*a.map{a+z}).map(&:join)-z|[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtLDkAwGAavYuX3qB6AcJHG4mtFkKBpSag6ez1WM4sZs8sz9HUoGnuBZa62XA0wlhFVjmuzdrvakgx8hr6Quzv9LInLaR2XtHBetHcQBKmIRQTgh1Qdtf/iD6@jXhxv9QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 32 bytes

```perl6
{flat [\X~] '',|[xx] .comb xx 2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Oi0nsUQhOiaiLlZBXV2nJrqiIlZBLzk/N0mhokLBqPa/NVdxYqVCmoJ6YlKyOoKjbv0fAA)

Anonymous code block that takes a string and returns a list of string including the length zero permutation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
^LQSl
```

[Try it here!](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%5ELQSl&input=%22abc%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 112 bytes

```r
function(S,s=sapply)cat(unlist(s(1:nchar(S),function(X)do.call('paste0',expand.grid(s(rep(S,X),strsplit,''))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09CsMwDIX3XEQSmNCuhQw9Q5YMXVTbaQ1GEZYD7eldp0OXvunx8X5KW6e27uJr2gRnZ5Oxan6T54q75GQVDc8X8U8uOJP7ZRcK2@g5ZwRlq/EELr6UJYyPkkIvlah9cCFntZjmVB0AfdVWBL4CDccJ3KS74UD/5O6B2gc)

Things that make you go Argh, strings in R.

Expands out to the following

```r
cat(                                           # output the results
  unlist(                                      # collapse the list
    sapply(1:nchar(S),                         # for 1 to character length of S
      function(X)do.call('paste0',             # for each row from the grid paste characters together
         expand.grid(                          # create permutations 
           sapply(rep(S,X),strsplit,''))))))   # replicate the string X times and split.
```

So we produce a lists of `[['a','b','c']]`, `[['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]`, `[['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]`.
These are feed into `expand.grid` to produce the permutations.

Each row of the grid is pasted together with no gaps in the `do.call`.

As it is still in a list we apply `unlist` so that cat will be able to output it.

Comment: depending on whether you are allowed to output the list directly (it's asked in comments but as yet unanswered) you could replace `cat(unlist(...))` with `print(...)` (maybe `show(...)` will work also — haven't tried)

Comment: I could probably just get rid of them completely.  There could also be an argument put forward to remove the do.call

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lF`, 48 bytes

```perl
$"=',';map$k{$_}++||say,glob"{@F}"."{@F,''}"x$#F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FyVZdR906N7FAJbtaJb5WW7umpjixUic9Jz9JqdrBrVZJD0TpqKvXKlWoKLv9/5@YlPwvv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaHBf90cNwA)