# Convert to and from Base 94

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

## The challenge

Make 2 programs which convert decimal to and from base 94, or a bidirectional program.

## Base 94?

Base 94 is like any other base, but instead of 0 to 9 and letters, it uses ASCII characters 33 to 126. Not 127 because `chr(127)` is DEL. Not 32 because that's a *space*.

## Examples

```
0 - ! or empty string
1 - "
93 - ~
94 - "!
2020 - 6O
14233221 - 2-n8
```

## Scoring

For two programs, the score will be the sum of the byte count of both of the programs.

The bidirectional program is simply just the byte count. Consider it like a -50% to the score.

Comment: FWIW, base 94 is ok for encoding binary data but somewhat messy (and with a fair few wasted codes). 94^83 ~= 5.883e+163, 256^68 ~= 5.759e+163. Base 85 is neater.

Comment: *convert **decimal** to and from ...* Wait what?  So the input has to be a decimal string, not a normal `int` number?  In most programming languages that define a base / internal representation for integer types, it's base 2 / binary.  (For example, C guarantees that the object representation of integral type is binary, which determines how bit-shifts and bitwise booleans work). If you didn't mean base 10 input, perhaps you mean "serialize and deserialize a number to / from a base 94 string" or a less formal equivalent?  Decimal, hex, and base 94 are serialization formats for numbers.

Comment: @PeterCordes But most languages who use binary as inner representation of numbers has built-in i/o functions which accept decimal from stdin / print decimal to stdout. So I believe they are still decimals, to end users.

Comment: @tsh: These are programming puzzles for programmers, and the rules are talking about the implementation, not end-use.  The [default I/O methods](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/) allow writing functions that take integer args like C `void itoa_b94(char *out, int num)`, not only terminal read/print.  But the wording in this question would rule that out and restrict you to taking input via stdin instead of a function arg (many more chars), or taking it as a decimal-float, or as some other decimal-based representation, because `int` has no implication of or association with decimal.

Comment: @PeterCordes Data stored in memory only has meanings when you print it. Otherwise, they are only a serial of bytes (in most implementations). There is nothing different to say `841838136` or `2-n8` since they share the same byte sequence with the [GCC on TIO](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCVVwaa4JCUzXy/Djiszr0QhNzEzT0NToZpLQaGgCCiQpqGkmqKko26km2ehrmnNVfv//7/ktJzE9OL/uuUA). But I don't think output an `int` 841838136 should be allowed anyway.

Comment: @tsh: So you disagree with [the top voted answer on the meta Q&A](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2456/30206) that says functions can "output" via their return value? That's what makes it allowed for e.g. my answer to have an asm implementation of `int atoi_b94(char*p, size_t len)` instead of internally converting to `int` and then writing more code to print that with system calls for some OS. I'm not even sure I understand your point. The binary object-representation of an `int`, e.g. 4 bytes in a register, can represent a number just as well as a string of digits in memory.

Comment: @tsh: To put it another way, everyone (except you?) understands that this codegolf challenge is about converting between *numbers* and base94 strings.  Not necessarily between decimal strings and base 94 strings.  Many of the answers have a base94->number part that return a number in a numeric type like C `int`, x86 ISA dword, or JavaScript numeric, not print as decimal.  People wrote those answers *despite* the question being worded to exclude them, if you read it literally.  Related: [this one](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139104) is much more explicit about the number side, counting bytes

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree that a submission may be a function not full program. But when you say between "_numbers_ and base94 strings", what do you mean by _numbers_? base94 number is also a number. May I do nothing at all? I meant that when we say _decimal_, we are already talking about `int`. Because `int` has a default built-in which print / receive decimal, but not base 94.

Comment: @tsh: ok, that's a good point, you do need to rule out having the other side of the conversion be base94, making it a no-op.  I understand that some people say *decimal* or *hex* to mean `int`, but those people are not technically accurate; those are serialization formats for numbers.  `int` is binary.  So we need to be more specific than "number".  Given that it has to work for all I/O methods and languages, we don't want to say "integral type" or something.  Probably "decimal or numeric type" covers it, or "decimal or binary" to allow both of those options but no others.

Comment: Or just say "number"; it should be obvious to human readers that a no-op answer would be pointless.  But maybe desirable to exclude bases that are easier to convert, like 94^2 which might be easy in the same way that 8-bit bytes naturally split into 2 hex digits.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 + 31 = 73 bytes

**To base 94: 42 bytes**

```hs
(l!!)
l="":tail[s++[c]|s<-l,c<-['!'..'~']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixDsIgEADQ3a84GhM0haY9utiUL0EGQkSJ14ZIx8ZP99ThLe8R6vNGxMle@URCnA9km2baQiZX29ZFv9dZk4qzdlLIrpNv6T0vIa9gobzyusERllAggesVDAou5mdUgD3@Y0RjEAfPn5go3CvrWMoX)

Instead of using modular arithmetic, we generate the list `l` of all strings in the desired order and index into it.

The recursive definition of `l` is similar to [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74293/20260) for generating all strings, but modified to output strings in the desired order by appending the new character, and with a `tail` to prevent the analogue of leading zeroes.

**From base 94: 31 bytes**

```hs
foldl(\n->(94*n-33+).fromEnum)0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfbhvzPy0/JyVHIyZP107D0kQrT9fYWFtTL60oP9c1rzRX0@B/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCbmKBQrpCtJKSjlIMiKgDMxSBpJk/kDDSzbNQiv3/LzktJzG9@L9uckEBAA)

Iterates over the characters `c` of the string, updating the current value `n` to `94*n-33+fromEnum c`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 + 45 = 85 bytes

**To base 94: 40 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n:n*"?"and f(n/94)+chr(n%94+33)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfNCoQgEADgu08hQTCzHcoZLwaxz2I/olCzEkb09Lbf7ctPiT@hWsO0@2NevZZRPs238bLqANI7i90ST5DW2Y4Z6x3Tvmkz5jNJgQBJ8lUAEeugjHKsnFU00D@WmInMCw)

Python 3 would need 1 extra byte for `//` in place of `/`.

**From base 94: 45 bytes**

```python
g=lambda s:s>''and g(s[:-1])*94+ord(s[-1])-33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P902JzE3KSVRodiq2E5dPTEvRSFdozjaStcwVlPL0kQ7vygFyAXxdI2N/5dnZOakKhhaFRRl5pVopGtk5hWUlmhoamr@V1dU51JXAuI6EA3imPkDCSPdPAt1AA)

**Both to and from base 94: 86 bytes**

```python
h=lambda x:x*'?'and h(x/94)+chr(x%94+33)if x<''else x>''and h(x[:-1])*94+ord(x[-1])-33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpNCsIwFATgfU4RBXlJS7F5L4gp/hzBA4iLaisJ1LTUinHj1WO6cDEzfDDDZ7K9xxjtvqsf16bmoQoZHKH2DbcirI2W@c2OIqyMzomku/OwA2i7Z8vDAf6/c1Woi8zSpx@bxFkFUXxb17VcVcPo/CSscH54TUJKGUummCFmNMMSEzQSISoGC2CwTPnOO2NzSoWF38IP)

A Frankenstein's monster stitched from the two above functions that turns out just barely longer than their byte total. Since this function accepts both numbers and strings, care must be taken not to produce an error caused by an illegal operation by acting on the wrong type.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), (34 + 44) = 78 bytes

The 'Decimal to Base94' function prints the Base94 number to STDOUT, whereas the 'Base94 to Decimal' function actually returns the integer.

---

#### Decimal to Base94:

```c
f(n){n&&f(n/94)+putchar(n%94+33);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOk9NDUjrW5poaheUliRnJBZp5KlammgbG2ta1/7PzCtRyE3MzNPQVKjmUkjTMNC0VoApU4/JU9e0BokaYhW1NMYubIJV2MjACIfhJkbGxkZGWOyo/Q8A)

#### Base94 to Decimal:

```c
n;f(char*s){for(n=0;*s;n=n*94+*s++-33);n=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/POk0jOSOxSKtYszotv0gjz9bAWqvYOs82T8vSRFurWFtb19hYE8S3rv2fmVeikJuYmaehqVDNpVBQBOSnaSippsTkKekoAFlKmprW2MRjcMrU4daiiEvKzB@XjJFungVYrvY/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, Score 37 + 70 = 107 bytes

---

## Base 10 to Base 94: 37 bytes

```bash
dc<<<94o$1p|sed 's/\b \|$/ 33+P/g'|dc
```

[Try the test suite online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsIwEEX3nuJTAl2IpJnJJhA9gwfoxibRuplI4zJ3H6vg5sN78P5ya6ve6wbBUzDBITCCB020gydmIncAct0HKGmtOAkGIzhfMPxkK28Y0ZxijMFX4169lYyx2XnB3I0F8/FqH2PPSfG/@aa5SlHVDw)

Input is passed as an argument, and output is on stdout.

This works for inputs from \$0\$ through \$94^{23}-1.\$

This is probably sufficient, since \$94^{23}-1\$ is a huge number (46 decimal digits long — `2409576021839340871044919550282633620681129983` in base 10, or `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~` in base 94), and this is already much larger than most languages can handle.

---

If you want it to work for arbitrarily large inputs, subject only to memory limitations, use

`dc<<<94o$1p|sed 's/\\//g;s/\b \|$/ 33+P/g'|dc`

instead (which is 45 bytes long).

---

## Base 94 to Base 10: <s>78</s> 70 bytes

```bash
n=$1;for((;${#n};)){ r=$[94*r+`printf %d "'$n"`-33];n=${n:1};};echo $r
```

[Try the test suite online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BDsIgEETvfsWIGFoNh9rGqAR/wQ8wJlVL014WA70R/HWk9bCzmbfZmdfTD6m3Dh4jQawFBMvznXc2xxsOkk4roLNZAPMeLCSBcQ99BVugNxPkjP7WaSESaV6pHFwUiocNRVWWIV/4/dzs3L79uJGmHtsOTHBirazrh8o/gS5VVFEtPdyluZhMSukH)

Input is passed as an argument, and output is on stdout.

This works for inputs up to \$2^{63}-1\$ (bash's maximum integer). That's `9223372036854775807` in base 10, or `1**0#VEx9D` in base 94.

If you would like it to work for arbitrarily large inputs (subject to resource limitations), use

```bash
o()([ "$1" ]&&(printf %dz "'$1";o ${1:1}))
dc<<<`o $1|sed s/z/\ 33-+94*/g`94/p
```

(78 bytes long) instead.

Comment: It seems you have forgotten to write a program to convert from base 94 back to base 10

Comment: @Lyxal It must be too late at night here -- thanks, I somehow missed that.

Comment: No worries! I originally missed that myself!

Comment: For the first part, `rs -T` can help put each base-94 "digit" on its own line, which should shorten the sed part. For the second part, `xxd` with flags and then piping it to sed and then to dc should save some

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), Score 10 bytes

*-4 bytes overall thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
žQ¦Åв
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7AQ8sOt17Y9P@/oYmRsbGRkSEA)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
žQ¦Åβ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7AQ8sOt57b9P9/tJKRko6Cki6IyAMRFkqxAA)

Comment: -2 bytes in both programs: [`žQ¦Åв`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7AQ8sOt17Y9P@/oYmRsbGRkSEA) and [`žQ¦Åβ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7AQ8sOt57b9P9/tJKRko6Cki6IyAMRFkqxAA)

Comment: Nice @KevinCruijssen I had toyed with `žQ¦` but didn't find `Åв` or its counterpart

Comment: You can search for 'custom base' to find them. ;)

Comment: I am new here. By what count is this program "žQ¦Åв" 5 bytes long, considering it has non-ascii characters and would be 9 bytes in utf-8? Which Codepage is assumed?

Comment: Hi @masterxilo 05AB1E has a custom code page, including unprintable ascii characters. For ease of being able to write it we use the custom code page (although in theory we could create the file with the unprintable characters). See: https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md

Answer (score 3):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Encoding/Decoding program, it's bidirectional.

```
lpQB
```

## Explanation

```
lp   % All printable characters, including the space.
  Q  % Extract all of the string except for the first item.
   B % Convert the input to/from base 94 using the custom base.
```

Comment: @PkmnQ I guess a bidirectional program is simply the bytecount, right?

Comment: Yes. I edited the rules.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>44</s> 43 + 32 = 75 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).

**Base 10 to base 94:**

```hs
g 0=""
g n=g(div n 94)++[['!'..]!!mod n 94]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P13BwFZJiStdIc82XSMls0whT8HSRFNbOzpaXVFdTy9WUTE3PwUsGPs/NzEzT8FWISWfSwEICooy80oUVBTSFQxNjIyNjYwM0YSNDIwM/gMA)

**Base 94 to base 10:**

```hs
foldl(#)0
n#c=n*94+fromEnum c-33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfbhvzPy0/JyVHQ1nTgCtPOdk2T8vSRDutKD/XNa80VyFZ19j4f25iZp6CrUJKPpcCEBQUZeaVKKgopCsoGenmWSihC5r5K/3/l5yWk5he/F83uaAAAA)

Comment: One byte shorter to index into a list of characters for the first one: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P13BwFZJiStdIc82XSMls0whT8HSRFNbOzpaXVFdTy9WUTE3PwUsGPs/NzEzT8FWISWfSwEICooy80oUVBTSFQxNjIyNjYwM0YSNDIwM/gMA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor thanks a lot. I tried it with `['!'..'~']` but didn't consider using an infinite list of characters.

Comment: A cute alternative there is `cycle['!'..'~']!!n`, but that's unfortunately longer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Base-94 I/O as an array of characters. Output for `0` is an empty array, input for `0` can either be an empty array or `["!"]`.

```
;ìEÅ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O%2bxFxQ&input=WwoxNDIzMzIyMQpbIjIiLCItIiwibiIsIjgiXQpdLW1S)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 34 + 43 = 77 bytes

## Encoder

```c
f(n){n&&f(n/94)|putchar(n%94+33);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOk9NDUjrW5po1hSUliRnJBZp5KlammgbG2ta1/7PzCtRyE3MzNMoy89M0eSq5lIAgjQNIwMjA01rrtr/AA)

## Decoder

```c
r;f(int*s){for(r=0;*s;)r=r*94+*s++-33;s=r;}
```

Takes a wide string as argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/IOk0jM69Eq1izOi2/SKPI1sBaq9has8i2SMvSRFurWFtb19jYuti2yLr2P1CdQm5iZp5GWX5miiZXNZcCEBQUAYXTNJRUU2LylHQU0jR8lMz8lTQ1rblq/wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 80 bytes

```
{FromCharacterCode[#~IntegerDigits~94+33]&,FromDigits[ToCharacterCode@#-33,94]&}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X52mk15r@7/arSg/1zkjsSgxuSS1yDk/JTVauc4zryQ1PbXIJTM9s6S4ztJE29g4Vk0HpBIiFB2Sj6LFQVnX2FjH0iRWrfZ/QFFmXkl0WrShiZGxsZGRYayOkoKCkk46slBs7P//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 or 7 bytes

### Base 10 to base 94: 5 bytes

```
⍘Ｎ✂γ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNfwzCsoLfErzU1KLdLQ1FEIzslMTtVI11Ew1NTUtP7/39DEyNjYyMjwv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a string of decimal digits optionally wrapped in `[]`. Explanation:

```
 Ｎ      Cast input to number
⍘       Base conversion from custom base
   γ    Printable ASCII (including space)
  ✂ ¹   Slice off the first character
        Implicitly print
```

### Base 94 to base 10: 6 bytes

```
Ｉ⍘Ｓ✂γ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwymxODW4BMhP1/DMKygtgbI1dRSCczKTUzXSdRQMNYHA@v9/I908i/@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Note: Due to the way Charcoal parses input, if the input looks like JSON then Charcoal will input it as JSON instead of a literal string. To avoid that, quote the input and wrap it in `[]`s, e.g. to input `[0]` use `["[0]"]`. Explanation:

```
  Ｓ     Cast input to string
 ⍘      Base conversion from custom base
    γ   Printable ASCII (including space)
   ✂ ¹  Slice off the first character
Ｉ       Cast from integer
        Implicitly print
```

### Bidirectional: 7 bytes

```
⁺ω⍘Ａ✂γ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMgp7RYo1xHwSmxODW4BCiUruGZV1BaoqGpoxCck5mcqpGuo2CoCQTW//9HKxnp5lkoxf7XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as JSON wrapped in `[]`s. Explanation:

```
   Ａ    Input JSON element
  ⍘     Base conversion to or from custom base
     γ  Printable ASCII (including space)
    ✂ ¹ Slice off the first character
⁺ω      Concatenate empty string (casts result to string)
        Implicitly print
```

Comment: The bidirectional program is impressive, the 7 bytes is ok. I'm gonna edit the question.

Comment: First time I see a golfing language use a descriptive emoji! If only all golfing languages used them, I could actually read those programs without comments. Perhaps.

Comment: @ComFreek Indeed, some of the functions do try to use somewhat related Unicode symbols, although I don't think there's a Unicode symbol for e.g. base conversion (I don't know why the developer picked that particular character).

Comment: By which codepage is this 5 bytes? Does the language at least have to restrict itself to 256 characters? Is the codepage for the program input & output assumed to be the same as the codepage for the program itself?

Comment: @masterxilo This language actually restricts itself to slightly fewer than 256 characters, but it has multibyte sequences that encode arbitrary Unicode characters if you really need them. I don't know what the rules on the code page for program input & output are though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 + 46 = 99 bytes

**Base 10 to base 94:**

```python
n=input();r=''
while n:r=chr(n%94+33)+r;n/=94
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoMwEEP3@4pbqoAYgIQFUEa6dukPtOlJoFaX6BTU8vVponayLT3b4YirZ52cfxBaVEolthuHPVb1LFYpeK/bi5AnsW6Vik/j0BhTNzJza8cBgmwcUVJuwp@9yk4TIEY5iiDShxyWByjeUYi4XM6LiJcfcBe6PVMHPYwG8qjudA6DNkbr/gs)

**Base 94 to base 10:**

```python
lambda s:reduce(lambda a,b:a*94+ord(b)-33,s,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU09D4IwFNz7K54ubRUSA8YoCSOuLI4uLX0EIrbNo0RZ/OtIo8N9JZc7P4fO2WxpnEEogTjnrC3vy6Ce2igYC0IzNSj@WSW6ULvLce/ICC3TPE/G5CAXT70N0Ire@ikIKVncYa@uHxBuNGHBAALNUQDwjQ3EQxZ9gz5AVV8rIke/giZUj4VvOOPbFZ@oMZzqlbLUnvkX)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47 + 51 = 98</s> 40 + 42 = 82 bytes

*Saved 12 bytes, inspired by @ovs 's suggestion.*
*Saved 1 byte by replacing `len(s)` with `s>[]`, stolen from [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203050/92237).*

```python
f=lambda n:n*`n`and f(n/94)+chr(n%94+33)
g=lambda s:s>[]and ord(s.pop())-33+g(s)*94
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BboMwEEX3PsUECckOhiY2qgpScoJKPUAUNRRKYgkGy@NNNr069VB1M57//5sv@2d8LGjWdTxN3fw1dIAt7m9463CAUeJLU6uifwSJeVMX1ipx/weppfPlytwSBkmVX7xUqrS2uEtS@6Ze3eyXEIGeJMS4BJgcfoNDNiqKg8NWAKCGTw0EJ5g7LymGFAXn9UZX5CcXUy2DCXEYJbKgd0cxGZceuLnfaq9MmeSmD3C@gazHvyMf0j1k@QA5QVmeYdsyyEGiJo1Gk1HrAUrYiWOamWhsen5EU7PaCXMwnL5@iGNtrDWGKVPi2y8)

`f` takes in an integer, and returns the base 94 string. Returns the empty string for `0`.
`g` takes in a list of characters, and returns an integer. If input is a empty list (representing an empty string), `False` is returned in stead of `0`, which is functionally equivalent in Python.

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes

This is the bidirectional function that combines the previous 2 functions, with the same total byte count. Utilize the fact that in Python 2, `0 < positive int < empty list < non-empty list`.

```python
f=lambda n:n>[]and ord(n.pop())-33+f(n)*94or n<[]and n*`n`and f(n/94)+chr(n%94+33)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BbsMgEEX3nGJiyRLEOE3AquqoyQkq9QBR1Dh2rSDZY8SwyaZXdweygfn/vz/gn/GxoFnX8TR1833oAI94vlw7HGAJg8SdX7xUqra2GiWqbdssAfDzReD2hrc0cPTWNqrqH0Fi2TaVtWp1s19CBHqSECO3Joe/4DAZO4qDw6MAQA0/GghOMHdeUgwcBed1pnfkJxf5@QQy4jDyH1jQl6PIxqWHtLnPa6@JMuyOMucZfOlc8oH7UJQDlAR1fYY8FVCCRE0ajSaj1j3UsBEHPgvRWr7@RNsktRFmb1L6/i0OjbHWmESZGj/@AQ)

**Input/output**: If `n` is a list of characters, return the converted integer. If `n` is an integer, returns its base 94 string.

Comment: You can do `f` without t: `f=lambda n:n*[n]and f(n/94)+[chr(n%94+33)]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 + 34 = 67 bytes

### Encode (33):

```ruby
f=->n{n>0?f[n/94]+""<<n%94+33:""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/OwD4tOk/f0iRWW0nJxiZP1dJE29jYSkmp9n9BaUmxQrSBjqGOpbGOpYmOkYERkGNiZGxsZGQYq5ebWKChlqb5HwA)

### Decode (34):

```ruby
->s{i=0;s.bytes{|x|i=i*94+x-33};i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OtPWwLpYL6myJLW4uqaiJtM2U8vSRLtC19i41jqz9n9BaUmxQrS6orqOuhIQ14FoEMfMAEgY6eZZqMfq5SYWaKilaf4HAA)

Thanks Value Ink, as usual, for some byte trimming.

Comment: [`i=0;s.bytes{|x|i=i*94+x-33};i` is -4 bytes.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OtPWwLpYL6myJLW4uqaiJtM2U8vSRLtC19i41jqz9n9BaUmxQrS6orqOuhIQ14FoEMfMAEgY6eZZqMfq5SYWaKilaf4HAA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: [Basic recursive function for encode is 36 bytes.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/OwD4tOk/f0iRWWyNP1dJE29hYUy85o8hKQUmp9n9BaUmxQrSBjqGOpbGOpYmOkYERkGNiZGxsZGQYq5ebWKChlqb5HwA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Recursive function dose not work with 0

Comment: empty string is now allowed for 0 so it works.

Answer (score 2):

### [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 9 + 10 = 19 bytes

### To base 94, 9 bytes

```
`c$33+94\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NKiFZxdhY29Ik5n@auoKBgqGCpbGCpYmCkYERkGNiZGxsZGT4HwA)

### From base 94, 10 bytes

```
94/-33+`i$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NytJEX9fYWDshU@V/mrqGkpK1UgyIqAMzFIGkmT@QMNLNs1DS5PoPAA)

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 + 13 = 28 bytes

### To base 94, 15 bytes

```
[:u:33+94&#.inv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61KrYyNtS1N1JT1MvPK/mtyKXClJmfkK2hYp2kqqNkBlRoqWBorWJooGBkYATkmRsbGRkaGXP8B)

### From base 94, 13 bytes

```
94#._33+a.i.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/LU2U9eKNjbUT9TL1Yv9rcilwpSZn5CtoWKdpKqjZKagrqlsrqCuBiDowC8w38weRRrp5Fupc/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 14 + 17 = 31 bytes

atoi: explicit-length string input, pointer and length. Returns `uint32_t`
itoa: pointer to the end of a buffer, returns pointer to the first digit.  Only works for non-negative `int32_t` - would cost 1 extra byte to `xor edx,edx` before div instead of `cdq` to sign-extend.

objdump -d -Mintel disassembly of both functions with machine code (the actual answer) and the source.  Comments added manually.

```
    ;; input: char *RDI, size_t RCX
    ;; returns: unsigned EDX
    ;; clobbers: EAX temporary to load digits
08049000 <atoi_b94>:
 8049000:       31 c0                   xor    eax,eax               ; EAX = 0 so lodsb zero-extends to 32-bit
 8049002:       99                      cdq                          ; EDX = 0 = total
08049003 <atoi_b94.loop>:
 8049003:       ac                      lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
 8049004:       6b d2 5e                imul   edx,edx,0x5e          ; total *= base
 8049007:       8d 54 02 df             lea    edx,[edx+eax*1-0x21]  ; total += char_to_int(digit)
 804900b:       e2 f6                   loop   8049003 <atoi_b94.loop>
 804900d:       c3                      ret
```

You could call atoi from C if you declare the return value as a 128-bit integer, or a struct.  itoa uses different calling convention.

```
    ;; input: unsigned EAX, char *RDI=end_ptr
    ;; result: converts into base94 in printing order in the buffer
    ;; returns: RDI=pointer to the first digit.  Caller knows where the end is because it passed that arg
    ;; clobbers: EDX
0804900e <itoa_end_base94>:
 804900e:       6a 5e                   push   0x5e
 8049010:       59                      pop    ecx      ; ECX = base
08049011 <itoa_end_base94.toascii_digit>:                         ; do{
 8049011:       99                      cdq    
 8049012:       f7 f1                   div    ecx                  ; EAX = quotient, EDX = remainder
 8049014:       83 c2 21                add    edx,0x21
 8049017:       4f                      dec    edi
 8049018:       88 17                   mov    BYTE PTR [edi],dl    ; *(--p) = digit
 804901a:       85 c0                   test   eax,eax            ; }while(x)
 804901c:       75 f3                   jne    8049011 <itoa_end_base94.toascii_digit>
 804901e:       c3                      ret
```

next address is 0x1f, total size = 0x1f - 0 = 31 bytes.

Some of the comments use 64-bit registers; I switched to 32-bit to save 2 bytes in single-byte `dec edi` vs. `dec rdi` REX opcode modrm.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##hVVNb@M2EL3rV0wPBezEcuKPtpsYOrgb7yJANgGStAjaDQRKGtlsZFJLUrGTon@96ZCUbDn2ojoIIjmceTPvzYhpjcukeAlzppdvb7lUS2ZgdvUJcI1pZVhSIIwAYOI2R8Mw4aZ1FmicL1EYUMgyZ9w6o331ArE2TJlgMi9kwop6aR1eT@@@BAH5hl@ndzPAbxWcjYM/Zrc3F5efL@/dxmjkLSYT4KKszDmkC6bg6Pbisgeav2Js4PbjQ2Oj0FRK6HOohOZzgRnMLjaHKQFIUNHpbPoABpelVIwAGgmFZBlkfM6N3gBlRvI4IUTNx7lztJYKANm6Z1@w@0yc5whOQVufmU7gFZUMcW1QZNpG8hV0ntLsG3zvmVjgzlNEtwwrgn4hZekheM/fu9iKSPlzQUFvp74IfFkVBD6z4O3L1X3fgwsIRxEkTKOPiAzqi3/SG45d8iFsyHpsXTyOHEmxkTFF77iydmvgsgRwmbg10fWe3i1x04feluyIsolLo7ZE66qwapDiGZXRPk@L92xM31Aq2uBiDlJlqOyOWSAkVZ6j2hOL9V9KukCW5MVa5lxp4xXRB/jIioLOnoRcaVgtUKEzIkzANSSYskojUGOUjPopo0NqIqbmB5RHcmwExo1ksc3Lww7erT3XZaUXdYf4ta0gUZGug6BPF3TKeexwnu8TmUn4@3@lRnZSFC@wkupJA00AEFKEAufM8Ge0hcU5YacyYEFZ2kxdEzQycgEy/lzDOhiAzCKFS8aFZSMiIax8ca3E@/2zvmupk2hw6vXAsgwawW005gNh6k/4gTDaSKLG97Hl/MvdReiZ3NVDzyVrlwlLn1ZMUW/mSi43rMrcfWpD1zyLS@kSJPXzxx5kxU7co04Yll3KxYX2KRiksH5SvB8UE/iHVMQL7Ky7E2f8l3ilvtihM5hYiVKaTpn6gDC3LTT5McOcC4T72d3979MrGAxH459@/uVDML26/HwN48BP3ZakBqceyVcBLLfCr9P2LbIRstyodFsFKgERr30L64omES16NNlaJnY@1mC8AKmD9gS/NU@dlHjQLrXzMd7jOI6vb@OV4gY9ZSeVVidcpEWV4Qn9xE4qwbXJ4tGwv9hxl5C7wZ67PCPa7u4vbn67jz9dXs2ub1oDr5l4ujweDWnoDR5rOdflcMk3AzV9T3KBYm4WdnKFrvo98DCt7iyVX4UfysLqBE7XH04PSNpl2hn0ai32oJE3oem264Wa74MgB/Vga4/xtB7joc9nFy@suFnIyjiIAleF1VXUHJJCfN@2WsNxu/1duq1l2dSlrQKNhpwlRRu2ZXnQKsSBOlDB19zEcyWrstNI/IfIhexYUTWb3W43eHv7N80LNtdvYVZvR4PxcDQaDgf/AQ)  with a test harness that converts an assemble-time-constant value to a string and back, prints the result, and checks for integer equality.  Change the assembler command line option to `-dTESTVAL=94` or whatever to test other values.  If it prints the right string and exit status is `0`, it worked.

I used FASM on TIO so I could make 32-bit code; TIO's will only assemble 64-bit object files with NASM/YASM, but FASM can output an executable directly, no linker involved.

---

For "normal" asm  [atoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309749/nasm-assembly-convert-input-to-integer/49548057#49548057) and [itoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894), see my answers on those linked SO questions.  Golfing them was straightforward, with only one significant change: use explicit-length strings for itoa so we can use `loop` instead of having to check for a terminator before `tot = tot*base + digit`.  And turning `itoa` into a function that just does the conversion into the caller's buffer.

I also made the `94` and `33` assemble-time symbolic constants (in the TIO link)

I had hoped we might get some use out of `stosb`, but we need to go backwards, and I couldn't justify having `atoi` depend on DF=0 while having `itoa` use `std` without `cld`.  Also, getting the remainder into AL means swapping with EDX, but then we need to swap back for the next `div`.

```
;; alternate worse version for after DIV
     std
     xchg   eax, edx
     add    al, ZERODIGIT        ; 2 bytes
     stosb                       ; *p-- = digit.  would also need a scasb or inc edi at the end to fix
     xchg   eax, edx
     cld
```

That's *nearly* break-even, IIRC one byte longer, but does `*p-- = digit` instead of the `*--p = digit` that we actually want.  (Caller could change to pass a pointer to the last element of the buffer, instead of past the end, but I don't think we can justify returning a pointer to the uninitialized space below the first digit.  So that would cost an extra `inc edi` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org) (raku -p) 60+42 Bytes = 102 Bytes

```
# convert base-10 to base-94
$!='';while $_ {$!=(chr $_%94+33)~$!;$_=$_.Int div 94};$_=$!

# convert base-94 to base-10
$!=0;$!=94*$!+$_-33 for $_.comb».ord;$_=$!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 68 + 58 = 126 bytes

### To base 94, 68 bytes

```
f: func[n][head either n > 0[append f n / 94 #"!"+(n % 94)][copy""]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCsMgFIXhPU9xaim0lFKjWdIhD9H1cgfRK2YxIsnQp7fmbB/8nCqhfSUQDy1@EI/sKTMlcQGy7kkqMhZocqVIDoidb8wTruqinveMW8eDyW/lpxRzi1sV51PPSGPEbM/YaNMxGWuNGZkG9JW65h3UQ/Va1HnMA7c/)

### From base 94, 58 bytes

```
g: func[s][either""= s[0][(-33 + take/last s)+(94 * g s)]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCsIwEITveYp1T9USFCvSCvoKgtdlhdBuf9BGSeLVV4@RVucyHwMz46SJF2mIY3eA9mVr8kwyhF4c4hE8bZgyXRSQQzA3Wd@ND@CXeVbtYAVdQubYPpyYugcPpCAJcbLrD97/YDHT/jzDVtsSFU/FpxtsAEp7YxpDfcLvBSuOHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>36</s> 32 + <s>26</s> 23 = 55 bytes

**To base 94:** (Commandline options: `-Minteger -n`)

```perl
do{print chr$_%94+33}while$_/=94
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8lv7qgKDOvRCE5o0glXtXSRNvYuLY8IzMnVSVe39bS5P9/QxMjY2MjI8N/@QUlmfl5xf91fYHqU9NTi/7r5gEA)

**From base 94:** (Commandline Options: `-pF`)

```perl
map$\=$\*94-33+ord,@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlxlYlRsvSRNfYWDu/KEXHwa22@v9/I908i3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xa4AQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 62 + 27 = 89 bytes

**To Base 94:**

```
param($a)for(;$a){$a-=$r=$a%94
$a/=94
$n=[char]($r+33)+$n}"$n"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9dCsIwEITfc4o1rDalLdYkqEXiFTyAiASJP1DTGgWFWq9ek1bwab6dnYWdunoadz@bsuzwURUSFDRdrZ2@MtTxsXJs5bVBnSl0CvW4kAT1VAWxans4a7dj6BIh4gRtS9HSriV4LE@/Zf7iC3lI4T/NBGF5ClEUp4TNPNCeCuHxM6AM7qhnnvMQnm@GuORCcB6ueGaXUQxvGDcEAC@2TgHNq/YNcB8cZ@6eJzD0CgHv0qCQrYcoTcKn254zc@tvdqTtvg)

**From Base 94:**

```
$args|%{$n=$n*94+$_-33}
+$n
```

Expects input via [splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7RCoIwFAbg@z3FSY6ZqaDbqLwweoMeIEIklgY2bV4kqL362pTo7js//4G/bd5CdZWoa4131TxTDhkMGgtVdqM7oMxQblMeYB4xNpEApZ4I3usyu9yqQl3jnu75LYT/lTCy8bwQYj80cIySWR@jlC3hyprP3p2NaUyXOo3kwX5wyhiliQ8juAMBwIdsQ0DRt2Ye5jZRojNew2/2yVRM7tgqRMel7AR262V2JF7z15VM@gs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 40+46=86 bytes

#### To Base 64, 40 bytes

```julia
!x=reverse(join('!'.+digits(x,base=94)))
```

#### From Base 64, 46 bytes

```julia
~x=sum(@. 94^(length(x)-1:-1:0)*((x...,)-'!'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BCoMwFET3nsJk4/9Wg8ZQaovgDXqBUrA0aMQqGG2z8uqpUAoJzGLgMfP6dVBNbqwlpprlW85aQj@pESISscNTtWrRYJJHo2VVCkS8bKbS6wtqFpbiDoMc26UDg2l@3pNhDGAYYwmm@wOirXU3fUICGQa/ugElFIPgD3IH3KhLysJBm0eEN/L@eMZd1/HqyQQvCs5dJ0/HE0X7BQ)

Comment: Your to and from base 94 is better, 40 + 46 = 86.

Comment: There is a semicolon or line break needed between the two though, so I thought that still counted

Comment: "For two programs, the score will be the sum of the byte count of both of the programs."

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll change that then

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 172 bytes

```python
def t(n):return"0"if n<1 else t(n//94).lstrip("0")+''.join(map(chr,range(33,127)))[n%94]
def f(n):return ord(n)-33 if len(n)<2 else f(n[1:])+(ord(n[0])-33)*(94**(len(n)-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwFET3fkUQivf6zgOK4p@IC6mxWuxVYrro16exLtrlYc7MbG87rSSdG/TILBDWRtuXobAM55FRw5ledn0kRVEpzJfdmnkDH2MSRfljnQme/Qa3yaSmp7sGKVMurojY0qVSXXAMj79htprBUyYl8weLJg@NOF@81vK6wwS@Ult2h4cxVCqO4XQzjug2M5MFC1wJKYXgmPruHyIG7gM)

Based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-in-any-base-to-a-string) answer on StackOverflow